# In R, how to change working directory more easily?

Tags: r, setwd

In how to change working directory more easily?
Currently, if we use 'setwd',we have to add many '\', sometimes it's boring
Is there any easier way for this ? (Just like Python can add 'r' )

```
setwd('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myfolder') # can't work
setwd('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\myfolder') # can work,but havt to add many '\'
```

Comment: Use forward-slashes; even on windows, `setwd('C:/Users/Adminstrator/Desktop/myfolder')` works. (BTW, running as `Administrator`? Seems like a really bad idea.)

Comment: I gather you're also aware of tab-completion, where you can hit tab and it will autocomplete the working directory with slashes etc included if you hit the first couple of letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `r` (for raw string) and add parenthesis:

```
> r"(C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myfolder)"
[1] "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\myfolder"
>
```

And now:

```
setwd(r"(C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myfolder)")
```

Or reading from clipboard automatically adds the extra slashes:

```
setwd(readClipboard())
```